# Burninate the 'links' tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

[links](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/links) is used for

- Hyperlinks (web sites, HTML emails, ...)
- Soft links and hard links on filesystems
- Library linking

Someone probably even used it for the [web browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Links_(web_browser))...

Therefore it is not useful in its current form (one could even say it is [ambiguous](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125234/a-real-solution-to-ambiguous-tags)) and should be cleaned up or burninated.

[image: Trog-signal]

Comment: Cleanse with fire!

Comment: Hear, hear -- I have run into this ambiguity five times in the past 24h.

Comment: [links] is back with 100+ questions. It needs to be reburninated!

Answer (score 1):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]